# Activate CharactersValidationBehavior after a Button was clicked

Tags: xaml, maui, code-behind

how is it possible to activate or re-evaluate the result of a CharactersValidationBehavior, which was set for an Entry, just after a Button was clicked?

```
<Entry.Behaviors>

    <toolkit:CharactersValidationBehavior IsValid="{Binding InputValid}"
                                          Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"                                                         
                                          CharacterType="Alphanumeric"
                                          MinimumCharacterTypeCount="1" />
                                                
</Entry.Behaviors>
```

The non-optional Entry is correctly set in XAML and evaluated in the InputValid-Property in Code-Behind of the ContentView as soon as the ContentView is displayed. But what I really want, is that the evaluation takes places right after a Button was clicked.

How could I do this?

Comment: there appears to be a `ForceValidate` method on the behavior

Comment: But this says "Forces the behavior to make a validation pass". It should not pass, though in my case, just evaluate again

Answer (score 0):

You can add the button event to verify after clicking, and then define the focus event of the Entry control. When the Entry gets the focus, remove the verification, so that the purpose of click activation or re-evaluation can be achieved. I wrote a demo to test it. You can refer to the following code.

Xaml file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiApp7.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="InvalidEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry" x:Name="invalidStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ValidEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry" x:Name="validStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="enrty" Focused="OnEntryFocused" >
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:CharactersValidationBehavior x:Name="charactersValidationBehavior"/>
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>

        <Button Text="Evaluate" Clicked="OnEvaluated"/>

</ContentPage>
```

.CS file:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;

namespace MauiApp7;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnEvaluated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        charactersValidationBehavior.InvalidStyle = invalidStyle;
        charactersValidationBehavior.ValidStyle = validStyle;
        charactersValidationBehavior.Flags = ValidationFlags.ValidateOnValueChanged;
        charactersValidationBehavior.CharacterType = CharacterType.Digit;
        charactersValidationBehavior.MinimumCharacterTypeCount = 3;  
        enrty.Behaviors.Add(charactersValidationBehavior);
    }

    private void OnEntryFocused(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        enrty.Behaviors.Remove(charactersValidationBehavior);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement your basic concept, but it seems as it did not work as I wanted.

Basically, I want a slight modification and want to show an Icon or a Label with a Text when the user input in the corresponding Entry is not validated correctly.

In my case, I have a ContentPage using a couple of ContentViews that host the Entrys and Labels, also the Label that should display the Error Message in red or something similar.

**Content Page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages.Views"
             x:DataType="viewModels:ManageItemsViewModel"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.ManageItems"
             Title="Some title">

    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <Label 
            Text="Addn Items"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Padding="20" />

        <StackLayout>
            <controls:MyItemInputControlView NameLabelString="Label for Input 1:"
                                             IsOptionalLabelString="Mandatory"
                                             PlaceholderString="a placeholder 1"
                                             EntryInput="{Binding Item.Name}"
                                             InputValid="{Binding NameInput1Valid, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <controls:MyItemInputControlView NameLabelString="Label for Input 2:"
                                             IsOptionalLabelString="Optional"
                                             PlaceholderString="a placeholder 2"
                                             EntryInput="{Binding Item.Brand}"
                                             InputValid="{Binding NameInput2Valid, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            

            <StackLayout Margin="20, 50, 15, 0">
                <Grid RowSpacing="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
                            Text="OK"
                            Command="{Binding SaveItemCommand}" />

                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"
                            Text="Cancel"
                            Command="{Binding CancelItemCommand}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Content View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages.Views"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Views.MyItemInputControlView"
             x:Name="this">


    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertBoolValueConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference this}">
        <Grid Margin="20, 0, 20, 0">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <!--<Style TargetType="Entry">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2 1" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
                </Style>-->
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="{Binding NameLabelString}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding IsOptionalLabelString}"  FontSize="12" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                <Entry Text="{Binding EntryInput}" Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderString}" Keyboard="{Binding KeyboardSetting}" Margin="5, 0, 5, 15" x:Name="entryControl">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>

                        <!--<toolkit:CharactersValidationBehavior IsValid="{Binding InputValid}"
                                                              Flags="ValidateOnUnfocusing,ValidateOnValueChanged"                                                         
                                                              CharacterType="Alphanumeric"
                                                              MinimumCharacterTypeCount="1" />-->

                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Label Text="{Binding NameLabelString}" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="{Binding InputValid, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolValueConverter}}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                <Label Text="{Binding MeasurementUnitString}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

**Simple SaveButtonClickedMessage**: used to send a message to a different ViewModel

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging.Messages;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels.Messages
{
    public class SaveButtonClickedMessage : ValueChangedMessage<bool>
    {
        public SaveButtonClickedMessage(bool value) : base(value)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView Code-Behind:**

```
namespace MyApp.Pages.Views;

public partial class MyItemInputControlView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NameLabelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NameLabelString), typeof(string), typeof(FoodItemInputControlView), string.Empty, BindingMode.OneWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsOptionalProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsOptionalLabelString), typeof(string), typeof(FoodItemInputControlView), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceholderString), typeof(string), typeof(FoodItemInputControlView), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty MeasurementUnitProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MeasurementUnitString), typeof(string), typeof(FoodItemInputControlView), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty KeyboardSettingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(KeyboardSetting), typeof(Keyboard), typeof(FoodItemInputControlView), Keyboard.Default);
    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryInputProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryInput), typeof(string), typeof(FoodItemInputControlView), string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty InputValidProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InputValid), typeof(bool), typeof(FoodItemInputControlView), true, BindingMode.OneWayToSource);


    public string NameLabelString
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(NameLabelProperty);
        set => SetValue(NameLabelProperty, value);
    }

    public string IsOptionalLabelString
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(IsOptionalProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsOptionalProperty, value);
    }

    public string PlaceholderString
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty);
        set => SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value);
    }

    public string MeasurementUnitString
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MeasurementUnitProperty);
        set => SetValue(MeasurementUnitProperty, value);
    }

    public Keyboard KeyboardSetting
    {
        get => (Keyboard)GetValue(KeyboardSettingProperty);
        set => SetValue(KeyboardSettingProperty, value);
    }

    public string EntryInput
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(EntryInputProperty);
        set => SetValue(EntryInputProperty, value);
    }

    


    public bool InputValid
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(InputValidProperty);
        set
        {
            // Before everything is initialized TextValidation should be valid
            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsOptionalLabelString) || IsOptionalLabelString.Equals("Optional")))
            {
                value = true;
            }

            SetValue(InputValidProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public MyItemInputControlView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += MyItemInputControlView_Loaded;
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<SaveButtonClickedMessage>(this, HandleSaveButtonClickedMessage);
    }

    private void HandleSaveButtonClickedMessage(object recipient, SaveButtonClickedMessage message)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("IsValid", BindingMode.TwoWay);
        charactersValidationBehavior.SetBinding(InputValidProperty, binding);

        charactersValidationBehavior.Flags = ValidationFlags.ValidateOnValueChanged | ValidationFlags.ValidateOnAttaching;
        charactersValidationBehavior.CharacterType = CharacterType.Alphanumeric;
        charactersValidationBehavior.MinimumCharacterTypeCount = 1;

        entryControl.Behaviors.Add(charactersValidationBehavior);
    }

    private void MyItemInputControlView_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entryControl.Behaviors.Remove(charactersValidationBehavior);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel of the ContentPage:**

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;
using MacroCalculatorApp.Models;
using SQLite;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class ManageItemViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private MyItem myItem;


        
        private bool InputsValid => true; // needs further evaluation if everything on the ContentView is correct



        [RelayCommand]
        async Task SaveItem()
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SaveButtonClickedMessage(true));

            try
            {
                if (InputsValid)
                {
                    ...

                    // Just navigate to the previous page
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException sqliteException)
            {
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", e.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task CancelItem()
        {
            // Just navigate to the previous page
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }

        public ManageMyItemViewModel()
        {
            MyItem = new MyItem();
        }
    }
}
```

I send a simple Message (just containing the value true) to the Code-Behind of the ContentView to detect the Button-Click.

Unfortunately, when I assign the CharactersValidationBehavior, **it does not evaluate the Entries of the ContentViews**. Also, the value of the Bound **"InputValid"-Property was not set correctly** and could be false when debugging and the Label is then visible and displays the red error Message, when the ContentView is displayed. This I can maybe surpress with the "Mode=TwoWay" Option in the Label itself. Therefore, the Error-Label was always displayed, also already when my ContentView was loaded.

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should edit this into the question instead of posting it as an answer. You said: "it does not evaluate the Entries of the ContentViews", that is, `CharacterValidationBehavior` does not work in your project, right?

Comment: Sorry, thought I should post it as a new answer to my post as it had a lot of source code and comments do not allow so many characters. Yes, my CharacterValidationBehavior is not evaluated correctly after it was assigned with the Button-Click. It does not change the „IsValid“-Flag and „InputValid“-Property. They are not evaluated after they are assigned and bound. The other problem was that when the ContentView is loaded the „InputValid“ and bound „IsValid“-Flag are „false“ in the beginning and the Label for the Error-Message are already displayed.

Comment: Is there a good way to debug this? I was wondering why my InputValid and IsValid Properties are reached so many times while the view was loaded and first evaluated with true and afterwards with false. I think it is due to the different DataBindings? So one time it provides true and then false, but why? I changed it to „Mode=TwoWay“ and got IsValid = true finally. But assigning the CharacterValidationBehsvior wasn’t evaluated when added to the Entry-Behaviors

Comment: If you don't bind, will `CharacterValidationBehsvior` work fine if `IsValid = true` is given directly?